# Could not deploy Spring-Boot war in tomcat with maven.compiler.source 1.8

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, java-8, war

I have written a simple getting started spring boot web application that I want to deploy in a tomcat (8.0.28).

Here is the Application.java file:

```
package deployablewarsample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

, the HelloWorldController.java file:

```
package deployablewarsample;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

and the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>getting-started-deployable-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <spring-boot.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I could build the project with mvn clean install and deploy the war in the tomcat without an error. But when I call http://localhost:8080/getting-started-deployable-war-1.0.0 I get an 404.

If I change the Java Version to 1.7 or remove the compiler properties, rebuild and deploy the application again, then I can see in the tomcat start console, that Spring Boot starts and when I call http://localhost:8080/getting-started-deployable-war-1.0.0 I get Greetings from Spring Boot!.

Is it possible to use Spring with Java 8 and the compiler properties? Because otherwise I get a Eclipse (EE, Luna) error (Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer...) and a rebuild of the project moves back to Java SE 1.5?

Comment: I am not understanding your question here. Do you want to know if we can compile it with java 8 and deploy to tomcat server?

Comment: Hi, Spring Boot does not start (without an error message) when I deploy the war file in a tomcat if I use the posted pom.xml. Spring Boot starts while deploying if I remove the 2 compiler properties or if I change 1.8 to 1.7. It would be nice, if I can use the compiler properties with java 1.8 because otherwise I get the described Eclipse problems. My question is, if there is a way to use the compiler properties together with java 1.8 or if I must search a solution to manage the Eclipse problems?

Comment: So looks like your tomcat supports only java 1.7 based on what you say. Why not set your eclipse compiler and jre preference to java 1.7, that way your eclipse will be happy.

Comment: I noticed, that my tomcat starts with java 1.7. I could use the compiler properties with java 8 after changing the JAVA_HOME to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25. Thanks, Hermann

Comment: @user3879863 If you found a solution please provide the answer and accept it.